# using $(this) inside jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, this

Here is my plugin code below.

```
$.fn.myplugin = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        my_data_title11:"",
        my_div:".getslow",
    }

    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    return this.each(function(){
        console.log(options.my_data_title); 
    });
}
```

I am calling this plugin from an external page like this...

```
$('#o_vari,#0_var2').myplugin({
    my_data_title11:$(this).attr("id"),my_div:'.getfast'
});
```

but it is displaying `undefined`. I am aware `my_data_title11:$(this).attr("id")` is not recognizing `$(this)` the calling statement, I even tried putting this exteral variable , but still the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried using `.each()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you have written the code, I'm assuming you wants to print `o_vari` and `0_var2`... but that is not the case because in the context in which you have used `$(this).att('id')`, `this` does not refer to the `o_varx` element.

So if you want the desired output try

```
$('#o_vari,#0_var2').each(function () {
    $(this).myplugin({
        my_data_title: this.id,
        my_div: '.getfast'
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s2BgF/)